# How often should one serious about bodybuilding have a cave day?

Tags: diet, bodybuilding, sugar

So I am a bodybuilder and I cave every 10 days, which doesn't seem that bad really, but how often should a bodybuilder actually cave. How frequently? How rarely?

Comment: You're referring to **cheat day** ?

Comment: Well I suppose it depends How often do you train? Do you bulk and then cut or do you just go for lean gains?

Comment: Came here for spelunking advice :(

Answer (score 2):

This is purely my opinion based on my experiences as a bodybuilder.  The answer to your question is twofold.  If you’re competitive, or, plan to be, you should look at having one “cheat” day per week as a general rule.  The other 6 days, you should try to eat as clean as possible.  If you aspire to that eating goal, your diet would be optimum **86%** of the time.

```
52 days per year cheat/365 days = ~14.24%
```

For the sake of sanity and food urges, that’s a goal I had no problem achieving and I think it’s achievable by anyone serious about fitness in general.

If, on the other hand, you plan to enter competitions, you’ll need to become much more serious about your eating, and, plan every aspect of your diet.  Right down to when and how often you eat. The closer you get to a competition, the tighter and cleaner your diet should be.